# Ripple effect of buttons still playing when getting back to screen

Tags: flutter

I have a simple app with elevated buttons, which push other screens to the Navigator when pressed. When I press a Button on Screen A, Screen B opens. Now, when I go back to Screen A, by poping the Navigator, you can see how the ripple effect on the originally pressed button is still playing for some ms.
ChatGPT says, it's because the screen will be restored with its state of animations, but how to prevent this? It's making the app look a little bit buggy.

Comment: I got the same issue, but I can't find a fix for that

Comment: I found out, that this glitch won't occur, if the button is on a screen that was opened via MaterialPageRoute() with allowSnapshotting or maintainState set to false. Both seem the have the same effect. But if the buttons are on your first screen, you don't have the possibility to set these booleans, as you don't navigate via to the screen MaterialPageRoute

Comment: I'm just using pushNamed, I guess there is no way for me to fix it

Answer (score 1):

I've turned around this problem using a **Future.delayed**.

For example:

```
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 300), () {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/person/');
});
```